# Find and replace special characters

Tags: find-and-replace, characters

How can I replace this character (_) with this one (:) in a list of filenames? The filenames are like this: 1_0_1_1AE1_7F6_2_11A0000_0_0_0.png The problem with character replacement programs is that the : character is illegal for filenames so they return errors.

Any ideas on how to bypass this?

Comment: Please include the operating system you are working with.

Comment: You want to **actually** rename the files, or to get a textual list and replace the characthers in a text editor or something?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would write the script, but, as you mention in the OP, you still have the issue of the : being an illegal character. And IMO there is no way around this on Windows, illegal characters cannot be used!

```
@echo off
echo Enter Filename
set /p name=
set newName=%name:_=:%
ren %name% %newNname%
```

This is within a loop

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=;" %%name in ('dir /b FOLDERNAME') do (
set newName=%%name
set newName=!newName:_=:!
ren %%name !newName!
)
```

Comment: You need to add `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and change the `%newName%`'s to `!newName!` in the `for` loop version :)

Comment: Just move the `setlocal` line above the `for` and change `%newName:_=:%` to `!newName:_=:!` and your good to go :) However, I don't know if this will allow colon's in filenames? At least on windows.

Comment: ah man.. I just actually tried it - instant fail! Thanks @BaliC

Comment: %variable - Specifies a **single letter** replaceable parameter, so %%name is actually incorrect (it might work since it's being truncated to a single letter, but it *is* incorrect).